# Best way to insert footer on certain pages Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I added footer component in app.blade.php

```php
@if(!isset($noFooter))
@include('footer/full')
@endif
```

As you can see there is that `if` that checks is the variable is present. If it is then the footer is inserted. I think that this is a bad practice and I wonder how can I make this better.
I want to show footer on all pages except a few, like login/register page, my account page etc.
So at this moment I just pass this variable `$noFooter` in controller to the routes that I don't want the footer. Do you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by checking current url usign `\Route` facade. Something like below code may help you:

```
@if(in_array(\Route::currentRouteName(),['login', 'register']))
    @include('footer/full')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about bad practice, but if there is a condition, there would be "if" somewhere.

You mentioned that only a few pages won't show the footer, you can check whether the current page is in the list.

```
@php
    $pageList = collect(['login', 'register']);
@endphp
@if(!$pageList->contains(request()->path()))
    @include('footer/full')
@endif
```